# How show jsPDF data on image

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jspdf

I am exporting some charts created in d3 to PDF. I am using jsPDF lib to achieve this. For instance I created a pdf as follows-

```
var pdf=new jsPDF('p','mm',[200,300]);
pdf.addImage(...); 
pdf.addImage(...);
pdf.rect(...);
...
```

Now I want to display this pdf in an image element on html page.
Is there any way to do this? May be if I can get data from this pdf,Something like-
pdf.getData();

Comment: please clear your question ..what exactly is your intention ?

Comment: @JafferWilson I just want to display the generated pdf in an image (<img src>)element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use third party library to render pdf in javascript. For example

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: can you please explain  a little bit?

Comment: if you'd like to convert PDF generated on client side into an image and display contents of the oducment this way you will need a third party library, simlar to jsPDF to do this